# Uploading a file with NSURLSession

Tags: ios, iphone, file-upload, ios7, nsurlsession

I am trying to upload a file with the following method:

```
- (void)uploadWithTarget:(NSString *)url andFileData:(NSData *)file andMD5Checksum:(NSString *)checksum
 {


NSURLSessionConfiguration *defaultConfigObject = [NSURLSessionConfiguration defaultSessionConfiguration];
NSURLSession *defaultSession = [NSURLSession sessionWithConfiguration: defaultConfigObject delegate: self delegateQueue: [NSOperationQueue mainQueue]];

NSURL * urll = [NSURL URLWithString:url];
NSMutableURLRequest * urlRequest = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:urll];
[urlRequest setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
[urlRequest addValue:checksum forHTTPHeaderField:@"Md5Hash"];
[urlRequest addValue:@"Keep-Alive" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Connection"];
[urlRequest addValue:@"xml" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];
[urlRequest setHTTPBody:file];


NSURLSessionDataTask * dataTask = [defaultSession dataTaskWithRequest:urlRequest];
[dataTask resume];


}
```

Delegate:

```
- (void)URLSession:(NSURLSession *)session dataTask:(NSURLSessionDataTask *)dataTask
didReceiveData:(NSData *)data
{
NSString * str = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:data encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
NSLog(@"Received String %@",str);
}
```

But i always get the error from my server that there isn´t a file attached! What´s wrong?

Comment: The content type of your HTTP request needs to be multipart/form-data. Also the body must be formed as a multipart request. You can find a tutorial here: http://web.archive.org/web/20140311092840/http://zcentric.com/2008/08/29/post-a-uiimage-to-the-web/

Comment: That looks good, but how to get dynamic NSSTrings into filename here: [body appendData:[[NSString stringWithString:@"Content-Disposition: form-data; name="userfile"; filename="ipodfile.jpg"rn"] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];

Comment: Using for example NSString's stringWithFormat

Comment: how do check  checksum after uploading completes

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Swift, checkout [Just](https://github.com/justhttp/Just). Example from the readme file:

```
//  talk to registration end point
Just.post(
    "http://justiceleauge.org/member/register",
    data: ["username": "barryallen", "password":"ReverseF1ashSucks"],
    files: ["profile_photo": .URL(fileURLWithPath:"flash.jpeg", nil)]
) { (r)
    if (r.ok) { /* success! */ }
}
```

Comment: Do `Just` has support for upload progress?

Comment: @MickeyMouse Yes, there's a [specific API](http://docs.justhttp.net/QuickStart.html#upload-and-download-progress) for that.